# Android Studio flashcards with images

Tags: android

I want to do it like this:

1. app shows image
2. user thinks of an answer what it is
3. user clicks the image
4. the answer shows up
5. the button "next" shows up
6. user clicks next button, and another image shows up

any help? im using udemy tutorials, but its so long, any hints?

```
package com.example.wot2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton btnSzeregowy;
    TextView txtWynik;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtWynik = findViewById(R.id.txtWynik);
        btnSzeregowy = findViewById(R.id.btnSzeregowy);
    }

    public void szeregowyButtonPressed (View buttonView) {

        txtWynik.setText("SZEREGOWY");
```

[android studio screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZM9t.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question!
But in general, start with a simple app till you get familiar with developing android apps, you can check github repositories that implement a similar idea to yours and learn from their implementations, try to understand what they're doing and incrementally work on your app.

Comment: I added a code and a screen, check it out. Now I want to make a 'next' button, so that the first image and first textview disappear and a new come up. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: well, good start! keep going, in the simplest form, you can add a button in your xml, then in your java activity implement its functionality like this: Button button = findViewById(R.id.button_id);
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 // make your image be invisible here 
btnSzeregowy.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
          }
         });

Comment: "Button" is a problem that has been solved before. You don't need to ask people, but rather the internet. Generally the Android documentation and docs for the language are the thing to scour.